# Is there any point in overpaying a merchant?

Tags: banished

I'm simply wondering if there is any positive outcome to overpaying a passing merchant in the trading post? Anything, really.

I just want to make sure there is no "investment" or "reputation" element to the trading system that I would have missed until now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only reason to "overpay" is because you don't have "exact change".  For this reason I keep my trading post stocked with small quantities of several  low value trade goods such as logs, fish, and eggs.  The bulk of my trading is in higher value goods such as firewood, coats, and red meats.